# displaying html tags as html in input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, orchardcms

Are there any possibility to do something like that? 
Or how I can simulate input field with possibility input usual text and display html tags as html?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess he means doing it by using the Orchardcms, but I have no clue what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 property *contenteditable*, if you can use this technology.
Exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/hZWWd/
I'm sure with some javascript you can add some buttons to put in bold or else for exemple (by adding some tags), and you have your own richtextbox.

Hope I didn't misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found "reach text editor" in jquery and it's exactly what I need;

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contenteditable` attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/AnWej/

```
<div contenteditable></div>​
```